# SQL Azure to SQL database

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Most of the posts out there discuss converting a SQL database to Azure. Actually, I want to go the other way.

I have an azure database and now I want to convert it back to sql including the data. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Export the SQL Database out to then use SQL Server 2012 and import it using

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh335292.aspx - How to Export

http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2012/06/easily-restore-sql-azure-database-to-local-sql-instance/

The above links should help.